# Production EKS deployment is failing on secret map

Tags: amazon-eks

We have 2 Clusters
US-East-2 QA/Dev cluster - Everything deploys without an issue
US-East-1 Production cluster - gives an error when trying to map the secrets share
Both are configured the same
Error msg:
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline-db" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod enterprise-production/enterprise-web-589994cf57-65h4q, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = us-east-1: Failed fetching secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:secret:rds-xxx-xxx-xxx: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials caused by: AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity status code: 403, request id: bd09ac7c-c0e8-49f4-98e6-905c8174c1c7
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[secrets-store-inline-db], unattached volumes=[secrets-store-inline-db kube-api-access-d8rgs aws-iam-token]: timed out waiting for the condition
(combined from similar events): MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline-db" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod enterprise-production/enterprise-web-589994cf57-65h4q, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = us-east-1: Failed fetching secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxx:secret:rds-xxxxx-xxxx-XXXX: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials caused by: AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity status code: 403, request id: bd157f5d-5852-49d2-806b-3dd2f1e18583

The service account is setup:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxxxxxx"
},
"Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
"Condition": {
"StringEquals": {
"oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxx:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
"oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:*:*"
}
}
}
]
}

Values.yaml for Prod
image:
repositoryBase: xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

serviceAccount:

## Annotations to add to the service account

annotations: {
"eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/eksctl-Prod-Cluster-addon-iamserviceaccount-Role1-8JPAZJ72W4N1"
}

ingress:
cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxx:certificate/0acb6fce-e94a-48f9-9405-4470dd28ecb1"
group: "prod-alb"

environment:
target: production
env: [
{ name: REDIS_HOST, value: "prod-xxxx-redis.mtalpw.ng.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com" }
]

secrets:

- name: prod-db
  secretname: rds-xxx-xxxx
  region: us-east-1
  object: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxx:secret:rds-xxx-xxx-xxx
  paths:

  - path: "username"
    objectAlias: "db_username"
  - path: "password"
    objectAlias: "db_password"
  - path: "host"
    objectAlias: "db_host"
  - path: "port"
    objectAlias: "db_port"
    data:
  - key: "DB_USERNAME"
    objectName: "db_username"
  - key: "DB_PASSWORD"
    objectName: "db_password"
  - key: "DB_HOST"
    objectName: "db_host"
  - key: "DB_PORT"
    objectName: "db_port"

volumes:

- name: secrets-store-inline-db
  csi:
  driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
  readOnly: true
  volumeAttributes:
  secretProviderClass: "prod-db"

We have tried creating new service accounts still nothing.  Changing other parts in the yaml and still no go.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was in the IAM account

```
"Condition": {
     "StringLike": {
```

Changed the condition to the below

```
"Condition": {
     "StringEquals":  {
```